# Wolfram Script doesn't even start when there is no internet connection

Tags: bugs, scripting

I wrote a Wolfram Script, and I tried it when there was no internet connection. It couldn't run at all. I tried it many times.

PacletInstall::dwnld:
   An error occurred downloading paclet CloudObject-11.1.1331 from site
    http://pacletserver.wolfram.com: Network error. Couldn't resolve host name

The script works after I disabled Automatic Updates in Mathematica's preferences.

**Update**

After I enabled Automatic Updates and run the script again, I saw something different. "Updating from Wolfram Research server ..." It's unpredictable.  To be able to run Wolfram Script any time, I have to disable Automatic Updates.

I tried it on another computer which disabled the Wi-Fi, however I couldn't reproduce it. I guess the Automatica Updates is done for this time on this computer. How about next time of Automatic Updates?

I think it's a bug. Wolfram Script should always be executed not matter there is an internet connection or not.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce with 11.1.0 using `wolframscript -code Mean[Range[10]]` with internet connection disabled.

Comment: @Edmund I guess the updating is done on your computer this time.